# Loading tableview with results displaying bottom to top Xcode?

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have a kind of predictive text uitableview that loads above my url bar when typing starts. After a url is entered and web view starts load it is added to the array so next time user starts typing the same url or at least the first letter, it is displayed in the tableview.
i.e. a = apple.com next row = amazon.com then empty space down to the url bar which is right above the keyboard.
I would like to have the results displayed bottom to top so the first result is displayed right above the url bar as opposed to the top of the whole view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that when there is only one cell to be displayed, you want it to be displayed right above the 'url bar'.

If so, try flipping the table itself vertically, as well as all the cells (or their contents).

Comment: OK, so I got it flipping but can I set it to appear already rotated? No animation? 'CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14); tableView.transform = transform; cell.transform = transform;' well actually it seems to only rotate on first launch then stays that way until the app is stopped and started again. Can I get it to not animate and just display already rotated? Thanks Again,

Comment: I would rather use CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,-1.0), but rotation should work fine, too. It should actually not animate... can you share some code?

Comment: That is the code above. = CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14); tableView.transform = transform; cell.transform = transform;

Comment: Just apply the transformation in your view controller's `-loadView` **after** calling `super`'s implementation, as well as for the cells in `-tableView:willDisplayCell:atIndexPath:`. What I didn't know before trying is that you will get serious problems with the separators - you may need to draw them by yourself.